# Is the Galois Group of $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ the product of the Galois groups of $g(x) \text{and } h(x)$?

Tags: galois-theory

If $g(x),\; h(x)$ are irreducible over the rationals, then the Galois group of $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ permutes the roots of $g$ and the roots of $h$ amongst themselves, separately. In other words no root of $g$ can be sent to a root of $h$ or vice versa under action of the Galois group of $f$ over the rationals?

Is this true? It seems true but I'm wary that there might be some special case that I have overlooked.

Comment: What happened if $g=h$? I think you need to exclude that case.

Comment: Ah thank you, I think this is an exceptional case. Ignoring the case where $g$ and $h$ have roots in common, it should prove to be true

Comment: You need the splitting fields of $g,h$ to be disjoint.  Your condition is too weak.  Consider $g(x)=x^2-2$ and $h(x)=x^2-2x-1$.

Comment: Taking the Galois group of $f(X) = g(X)h(X)$ corresponds to taking the Galois group of the compositum of the splitting fields for $g, h$. In general, we have an injection from the Galois group of the compositum to the product of the Galois groups, which is an isomorphism precisely when the splitting fields of $g$ and $h$ are disjoint, as lulu notes. See the first few pages of these wonderful notes by Keith Conrad: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorrthms.pdf